# Keeping local versioning file different from server files

Tags: version-control

My work uses Visual SourceSafe for versioning. When I worked on my local, I add or remove code as I make changes to the file. I want to keep a local repository for my files, In-case If I accidentally checkout from SourceSafe, or If my computer shut down for some reason, so I don't loose my changes. Sometime I modify a function, but I need to see what I did few days ago. I only checked in to SourceSafe the code that is bug free or final version. Can I use svn on my local on same folder that is used by SourceSafe? Any other process/suggestions. Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you don't want to check in every modification to your source control tool, the Shelve/Unshelve feature may fulfill your requirements. After you make the modification, you can shelve the files. This way, you don't need to check in the unfinished version, and on the other hand don't need to worry about losing the modifications.

I'm not sure whether SVN can do this. But you can try SourceAnywhere Standalone or TFS. Both of the tools support the shelve feature and provide easy ways to do the database migration from VSS.

Comment: Thanks windy for suggestion, but moving to TFS is not in my hand. I need to work with SourceSafe and figure out a way to not lose my changes.

Comment: If you have to use VSS (although not recommended), then you can try to create a branch for your project. You can always check in the modifications to the branched project. Once you think the version is bug free, you can merge it back to the original one. In addition, I suggest you back up the VSS database regularly.